# Using PrintOut for Adobe PDF with predefined path and file name

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to print a macro-enabled MS-Word Document that is embedded in a Excel Worksheet which it's name is `SalaryPaycheck`, from the excel macro module.

I using code below:

```
Sub PrintIt()

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Oshp As Object
    Dim strCurrentPrinter As String

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("SalaryPaycheck").Activate
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
    objWord.Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    objDoc.Application.ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF on Ne06:"


    objDoc.PrintOut Background:=False


    objWord.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub 'Print it
```

The `PrintOut` opens a dialog box which asks about path and file name.

I want to made file name and path predefined so `PrintOut` runs quietly.

Comment: Why not save as a PDF document instead of printing?

Comment: Because the `PrintOut` procedure has the `Append` method and I need appending several documents in a single pdf file.

Comment: That is a different question then. But you could join the several documents into a single word file first and then export it as a PDF file

Comment: The question asked [stackoverflow.com/q/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48059723/9075944).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an up-to-date Word version then you could export/save the file to a PDF document directly. Change your code to

```
Sub PrintIt()

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Oshp As Object
    Dim strCurrentPrinter As String

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("SalaryPaycheck").Activate
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
    objWord.Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
 '   objDoc.Application.ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF on Ne06:"
 '   objDoc.PrintOut Background:=False

    Dim strOutFile As String
    strOutFile = "<filename>.pdf"

    objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        strOutFile, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent



    objWord.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: This is cool, but it isn't working for me in excel as I am trying to print a specific range of cells.

Comment: I am afraid you have to be more specific as _"it isn't working"_ is not really helpful resp. describes anything. I think it's best you create a new post and explain what your specific issue is. BTW, did you try to define _print areas_?