# Relation between Running a program faster and CPU usage

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I'm using code from [Export several word documents appended in a single pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059723/export-several-word-documents-appended-in-a-single-pdf-file/48060961#48060961) for reference.

As I was commented, the above procedure included a `For Next` which needs more times repeat.

The performance is low while:

(I was monitored the Task Manager's, Performance tab (CPU utilization) and the processes tab together.)

The overall CPU usage is -approximately- lower than 25%.

Why the running procedure have not using more CPU resources to increase performance and running faster?

Is it possible for us to perform consuming more CPU usage (100%) for increase the running software performance?

Comment: performance are not only limited by CPU, you could be limited by memory usage/availability or by disk IOWait

Comment: How many cores on your CPU?  If the function is not multi-threaded, then it can only utilize at most 100% of one core.  If there's IO involved (writing to disk), then the CPU will be idle while waiting for IO

Comment: regards, How can I made my procedure multi-threaded to using 100% of overall CPU utilization in VBA? Point is seems the code is not IO involved. Please visit my code.

Comment: My CPU has 2 cores.

Comment: Adding to @dwilliss observation - Pure VBA works in single-thread unless you use some com objects written in languages that can support multi-threading.

Comment: Related discussion: [stackoverflow.com/q/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5721564/9075944)

Answer (score -2):

VBA is single-threaded, so it will always use only a single core.

Comment: Your answer really is a comment.

Comment: I find the difference between an answer and a comment isn't always that clear-cut. I posted this as an answer because there seemed to be discussion about whether or not VBA is mulit-threaded. IMO the thread needed a clear answer on that.