# Parent file address, in embedded word doc fields is absoluted

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, embedded-documents, word-field

How can made it relative?

I have `"WB1.xlsm"` in `"E:\Administration\Salary"`.

A **word document** was embedded in `Sheet1`: (Microsoft Word Macro-Enabled Document object)

I did Copy & Paste `Cells(2,1)` in the embedded word doc as `Paste Special`> `Paste Link`

There is an absolute parent file address have generated in the field's code:

```
LINK Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 "E:\Administration\Salary\\WB1.xlsm" "Sheet1!R2C1" \a \f 4 \r  \* MERGEFORMAT
```

**So I can't move the Excel file.**

How can make the parent file address which is in linked fields, **related** to the `application.path` of parent document? **parent document is Excel Workbook.**

Answer (score 1):

LINK fields cannot be made to retain a relative address. You may be able to resolve the issue by setting a hyperlink base, which MS wrongly refers to as setting a relative hyperlink. See:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/903163/how-to-create-absolute-hyperlinks-and-relative-hyperlinks-in-word-docu

Alternatively, for a field code solution that works with fields other than LINK fields, and a macro that works with all fields, see:

http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154379-Word-Fields-and-Relative-Paths-to-External-Files

Comment: Is it possible using `Custom Document Properties` , With add a Text type variable with the path value. and using this Properties value in the fields?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Using a Document Property requires the use of a DOCPROPERY field within the LINK field, but Word will convert the DOCPROPERY field's to static text immediately the LINK field is updated.